# Having assertions inside definitions in SMT

Tags: z3, smt

I want to capture the assertion inside fac.

```
int f( x )
{
     if( x == 1) return 1;
     else{
         assert( x > 0 );
         return 2;         
         }
}

int g (x)
{  assert( x > 5 );
   return f(x-1) + f(x-2);
}
```

I want an smt2 code for this. 
I can do this by striping the argument and making it global with unique name (also rename inside f), then do this 3 times each with a different name for function. Like below :

```
( declare-const x1 Int )
(define-fun f1 () Int 
            ( ite ( x1 > 0) 1 2 )
) 
(assert (> x1 0))

( declare-const x2 Int )
(define-fun f2 () Int 
            ( ite ( x2 > 0) 1 2 )
) 
(assert (> x2 0))

( declare-const x3 Int )
(define-fun g1 () Int 
            ( + f1 f2 )
) 
(assert (> x3 5))
```

I don't want to this. Is there any other way to do this without repeating ?

**EDIT**
My purpose is to find values violating the asserts.

Comment: And what is the semantics you want for these asserts? To find if they can ever be called with arguments that can violate them, OR, to restrict the eventual proof to only the values that satisfy them? While these two questions might sound similar, they are important in how you end up modeling this construct.

Comment: Thanks, its the latter that I wanted.

Comment: @JagadeepSai after the edit the *"accepted"* answer no longer answers your question. Either un-accept the answer, so I can self-delete it, or open a new question.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin I think your answer is perfectly acceptable; should remain as accepted!

Comment: Great.. What you're trying to do is neither easy, nor it would scale if you did it by hand. Since you seem to be interested in C programs, check out https://klee.github.io/ which will check these `asserts` for you automatically using symbolic simulation. (It'll use z3 as the underlying engine.) You can peruse their documentation to figure out how to do this in large scale.

Comment: I will keep the answer accepted as it solves my main problem of repetition. @alias Thanks for the resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As far as I know*, it is not possible to embed assertions within function definitions.

What I would try to do is to separate the expected behavior, the input assumptions and the output guarantees (if any).

**Example:**

```
(define-fun f ((x Int)) Int
      (ite (= x 1) 1 2)
)

(define-fun f-helper ((x Int)) Bool
      (< 0 x)
)

(define-fun g ((x Int)) Int
    (+ (f (- x 1)) (f (- x 2)))
)

(define-fun g-helper ((x Int)) Bool
    (and (< 5 x)
         (f-helper (- x 1))
         (f-helper (- x 2))
    )
)

(declare-const x Int)
(declare-const y Int)

(assert (and (= y (g x))
             (g-helper x)
))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

In this example we use `f` to model the behavior of the original function `f`, and `f-helper` to model the assumptions of `f`. The output, using the [online Z3 tool](https://rise4fun.com/Z3/5AEp), is as follows:

```
sat
(model 
  (define-fun x () Int
    6)
  (define-fun y () Int
    4)
)
```

---

I would conclude saying that this approach could become tricky as soon as `f` and `g` are used inside both positive and negative contexts.. in this case one should pay extra attention that the polarity of the assertions is correct wrt. the expected result.

Comment: This is a great way to model if you're interested in the `assert` as meaning: "only consider paths that satisfy my assumptions." An alternative might be: Find me the inputs that violate my `assert`s. Both are valid questions, and it isn't clear from the original question which one is meant. Great solution for the former though. An alternative might be to "pair" up the results: i.e., translate `g` to a function that returns the result together with a boolean; and then you can compose these nicely and assert all the "valid" predicates must be true.

Comment: @alias These are actually very good observations and suggestions! There's enough to create a second, better, answer actually :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out @alias. My main motive is to find inputs that violating the asserts.

Comment: @Patrick  What do mean by using inside positive and negative contexts. and also about the polarity ?